# How to create a iTextSharp.text.Image object startng to a System.Drawing.Bitmap object?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am pretty new in **iTextSharp** (the C# version of **iText**):

I have something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)ChartHelper.GetPdfChart((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10);

iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap);

vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img) { Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER, BorderColor = new BaseColor(79, 129, 189), BorderWidth = 1, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 30, PaddingTop = 10 });
```

As you can see I have classic **System.Drawing.Bitmap** immage named **bitmap** and I want put it inside a cell of a PDF document table.

The problem is that this line is signed as error:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap);
```

The error is:

> Error 75  The best overloaded method match for
>   'iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(iTextSharp.text.Image)' has some
>   invalid
>   arguments c:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\PdfVulnerability.cs   120 27  PdfReport

So I think that I need to obtain an **iTextSharp.text.Image** object from a classic **System.Drawing.Bitmap** object.

What can I do to do it? I am going crazy trying to do it.

Tnx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no overloads that take just a `System.Drawing.Image`. You need to used one of these:

```
GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, BaseColor color)
GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, BaseColor color, bool forceBW)
GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
```

The first one is probably the best choice and I'm 99% sure you can pass `null` for the `color` parameter.

Comment: Just to verify: you can pass null as the color. Code documentation: if different from null (the basecolor) the transparency pixels are replaced by this color

Comment: @Chris Haas I'm using a GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format) - why it always gets me a black rectangle instead my bitmap?

Comment: I used it for Barcode image insert into pdf file wit null for color:        Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
                System.Drawing.Image barCodeImage = barcode.Draw("*y21456*", 50);
                BaseColor color = null;
                Image image = Image.GetInstance(barCodeImage, color);

Comment: Using version 4.1.6.0 have to put some color. Altough have seen no difference using diffrent colors.