# Detect a corrupt image file

Tags: c#, itext, abstract-class, system.drawing.imaging

Hi All you clever guys,

Im faceing a bit of a challenge here.
Im supposed to create several different PDF's containing multiple (not similar) images.

Unfortunately some of the images are corrupt/defect. This causes the creation of the partikular PDF to fail/dump.

> Is there a way I can test the image prior to creation of the PDF?

Please be gentle with me. Im not an expert.

I found out that System.Drawings.Image can test some formats. Better than nothing I guess (it will reduce the subset significantly).

But when using iTextSharp.text.Image for the creation of the PDF's. Then I dont know how to use `the System.Drawings.Image` because when I try `Image newImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");` then it (Image) refers to the `iTextSharp.text.Image` class.

System.Drawings.Image is abstract, so I've tried to create a subclass.

```
public class ImageTest : System.Drawing.Image
    {

    }
```

Now I get the error message:`"Error 1   The type 'System.Drawing.Image' has no constructors defined"`
Trying to investigate which constructors I can use gives me this attempt.

```
public class ImageTest : System.Drawing.Image
    {
      ImageTest(string filename);
      {
      }
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

Please inform me if there is information you need which is relevant to you for investigating this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to use

```
public bool IsValidImageFile (string imageFile)
{
    try
    {
        // the using is important to avoid stressing the garbage collector
        using (var test = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageFile))
        {
             // image has loaded and so is fine
             return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // technically some exceptions may not indicate a corrupt image, but this is unlikely to be an issue
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works great.Max happy :-) Could you explain to me how Im supposed to create a subclass of System.Drawings.Image with a correct constructor. If you are aware of my lack of knowledge, then please guide me to relevant information. Again Thanks.

Comment: Try this : public class ImageTest : System.Drawing.Image
{
      public ImageTest(string filename) : base(filename)
      {
      }
}

Answer (score 1):

Catch OutOfMemoryException works:

```
try
{
    // Using System.Drawing.Image
    System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("myimage.png");
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
{
    // Handle the exception...
}
```

I tested it with this code:

```
try
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("myimage.png");
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error loading image...");
}
```

And I deleted a few characters in a `.png` file, and the console said:

> Error loading image...

And to convert it into a [iTextSharp.text.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548166/how-to-create-a-itextsharp-text-image-object-startng-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work here. Image refers to iTextSharp.text.Image

Comment: You just need to fully qualify System.Drawing.Image in place of Image